# proper fitness routine

Tags: gym, push-ups, yoga, toning, chin-ups

After so much reference from the Internet. I myself planned a fitness routine aiming for a lean and toned body like this in the following picture

[image: a perfect fit body]

I currently weigh 67 kg and 173 cm. I have planned my fitness routine as follows

```
           <--   Day 1  -->
           1. Stretching abs
           2. Squats (no weights)
           3. Cardio Activities like jumping 250 times and Fake Running for around 10 minutes i.e running  with legs motion at the same position (not moving) 
           4. Pull Ups (around 3 X 3)
           5. Push Ups (standard , declined and using fist)
           6. Abs (situps, bicycle crunches and lower abs excersise)

           <--   Day 2  -->
           1. Stretching abs
           2. Squats (no weights)
           3. Cardio Activities like jumping 250 times and Fake Running for around 10 minutes i.e running  with legs motion at the same position (not moving) 
           4. Chin Ups (around 3 X 3)
           5. Biceps and Forearms using dumbells (8 kg each)
           6. Abs (situps, bicycle crunches and lower abs excersise)

           <--   Day 3  -->
           Yoga particularly meditation , pranayama and asanas.
```

The following routine will be done every 3 days............
**Will this routine help me reach my goal** and are there any things to be avoided i.e **are these excersises contradictory or affecting each other in any sense**. For eg. I think, well am not sure that chin ups and push ups cannot be done the other day. Please add your opinions concerning my fitness routine.

Comment: It looks good enough. Why don't you try it and tell us?

Comment: The physical part looks all right, what are you doing for diet? That's just as much if not more of a component than toned muscles.

Comment: @JohnP  The Diet i have invloved is of normal type. not much carb or protein. Since i've heard low carb diet can lead to wrinkled skin and dark rings around skin.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann i could have....but i doubt on certain excersises like doing push up one day and chin up the other day since it might be overtaining and doing yoga once in three days may not be considered useful or effective. I just wanna know Is this routine OK since i m afraid to take any chances and get any negative effects ??

Comment: Nobody can tell you if you're overtraining except you. One person might do that workout and be undertrained, while another might do that workout and collapse from exhaustion. There's no way for us to tell how you'll do with it.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I have seen in many fitness blogs that working on same muscle group daily leads to overtaining......i doubt here since i believe chin up, pull ups and push up work on the same muscle group.......

Comment: That's mostly only true with heavy weights or lots of volume. You'll do fine. If not, then reduce the volume.

Comment: What is "Fake Running"? :D

Comment: @Chelonian fake running with your legs in motin with your position fixed i.e we are doing a running type activity without changing our current position as we do in a typical running.....

Answer (score 2):

> Will this routine help me reach my goal?

Yes.  They'll *help* you reach toward your goal, but whether you will reach your goal with them in a time acceptable to you is impossible for anyone here to say.  As someone mentioned, it all depends on how far you are from your goal and how vigorously you do these.

> and are there any things to be avoided i.e are these excersises
>   contradictory or affecting each other in any sense.

The main thing I would think to suggest is that you swap Day 2 and Day 3:  do the yoga in between the exercise days, so that you have an extra day to recover before you repeat some of these exercises for a second day in a row (and, in my opinion, that includes cardio, depending on your intensity).

Comment: if swapped day 2 and day 3 .... isn't it won't be the same since instead of chest day followed by arms day...it would be arms days followed by chest day ...right... i.e 
` day 1 -> day 3 -> day2 -> day 1 `  rite...

Comment: @Abhay Yes, it would, if you are doing these three every day without a break, which I see you did write.  So then, I'd ask whether exercising every single day is reasonable, and I'd suggest you 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2 where "4" is either a rest day or one in which you do yet a different activity, perhaps a good walk.  Rest can be quite important to results and health (though it depends on a lot of factors, like intensity, fitness level, age, muscle type, genetics, etc). Also, I think psychologically it is harder to stay on a program of exercise *every* day of one's life in this way.

Comment: and m also worried about my rest days.........as you i'll have to take 2 days rest for my proposed plan and 3 days rest i m looking with your plan.......i have also heard in certain articles than longer rest periods favour bulkiness and shorter rest period for lean toning....so am i taking longer rest period since i m focusing on a lean and toned body......

Comment: @Abhay The main thing is now, I think:  *start*.  :D  If you feel you're overdoing it, take a break.  But get going!  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This routine is good, I guess, but to get the body you want you will need to train more. I.e. you left out shoulder exercises(i.e. front-raises, traps, etc). Pull-ups and chin-ups won't be enough for your back to develop alone, try doing lateral raises, pull-downs, bend-over rows and deadlifts (be careful with deadlifts - wrong form/too much weight can f**k up your back and it's easy to tear muscles). For your biceps, chin-ups are pretty good for that and you're doing regular curls aswell. Try switching up the regular curls for something else once every 3-4 weeks(try preacher curls, cable curls, concentration curls, etc).

Push-ups is by far not enough for develop a nice thick, seperated chest. You will need to do benchpresses, dumbell-presses, fly's and perhaps dips. Dips and close-grip benchpressing will also develop  your triceps(keep in mind that the triceps is like 2/3 of your arm, so never skip these).

All-in-all: your routine will surely train your chest, biceps, triceps, shoulder and back a bit, but not enough to reach your ultimate goal. However, I can be wrong ofcourse. If  your muscles start developing and *you're* happy about it, then that is the most important thing.